# Conventional Vue structure for similar functionalities components (with Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

## Question about conventions on components with similar functionalities but only the getters and actions are different.

**How to keep the clean/maintainable while only the getters and actions are different?**
**Do I use mixin? Higher order component? Use switch cases?**
**And explain you choice if possible**

For instance, the following components are:

1. sharing the same `sameFunction1()` and `sameFunction2()`
2. the only difference is that the getters and actions are different

#### Component 1

```
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getDog1',
      'getCat1',
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'setDog1',
      'setCat1',
    ])
    sameFunction1() {...},
    sameFunction2() {...},
  },
}
```

#### Component 2

```
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getDog2',
      'getCat2',
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'setDog2',
      'setCat2',
    ]),
    sameFunction1() {...},
    sameFunction2() {...},
  },
}
```

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics

Comment: Can you explain how mixins pattern can be used for the situation?

Comment: I added an [answer w/ mixins pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60438233/12971257) below

Answer (score 1):

Based on Estus Flask [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427954/conventional-vue-structure-for-similar-functionalities-components-with-vuex?noredirect=1#comment106899308_60427954)

## We can use mixins and structure the component like abstract classes

#### Mixin

```
// define a mixin object
var myMixin = {
  methods: {
    sameFunction1() {...},
    sameFunction2() {...},
  }
}
```

#### Component 1

```
export default {
  mixins: [myMixin],
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getDog1',
      'getCat1',
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'setDog1',
      'setCat1',
    ])
  },
}
```

#### Component 2

```
export default {
  mixins: [myMixin],
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getDog2',
      'getCat2',
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'setDog2',
      'setCat2',
    ]),
    sameFunction1() {...},
    sameFunction2() {...},
  },
}
```